# How do you get text between tags using python and webdriver?

Tags: python, webdriver

I have
    `<a href="MENU.asp?navid=1">Property</a>`
and need to get the text "Property".  I found the href element but when I tried get_attribute("value") on it, it returns "None"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the value of the tag, its the innerHTML of the tag. So try to fetch that:

```
get_attribute("innerHTML")
```